# How do you normally redirects a user after they log in to an account in React router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So let's just say I forgot to log in, and I tried accessing a login protected page like this

```
'http://localhost:3000/main/login-protected-page'
```

so I got redirected to the login page with URL like this

```
'http://localhost:3000/auth/login'
```

so I've used Django in the past and they handle it like this

```
'http://localhost:3000/auth/login/next=/your/next/destination'

//or in this case

'http://localhost:3000/auth/login/next=/main/login-protected-page'
```

the idea being getting that `next` variable from the link and use it to redirect the page
how do you do this in `react-router-dom`?

and also feel free to leave a keyword so I can learn more or maybe suggest some better ways of doing this I would greatly appreciate it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the referrer when redirecting to login page as described [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/to-object).
Below is an example code.

```
<Redirect
    to={{
        pathname: '/auth/login',
        state: { referrer: location.pathname }
    }}
/>
```

In login page, you can redirect to the referrer URL after login. Below is the skeleton code.

```
const location = useLocation('')
// after login
return <Redirect to={location.state ? location.state.referrer || '/' : '/'} />
```